# Do Haitian need a transit visa for going through Cuba?

Tags: visas, cuba, haitian-citizens

I am Haitian Do I need a transit visa to go through Cuba? My final destination is Mexico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cuba provides 72 hours of visa free time as long as you have an onward ticket booked. Note that you will need a visa for Mexico. [Source](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b)

Comment: Today I was told that I do need a transit card and that the Cuban embassy can give you one. I have the tickets and the Mexico visa but no Transit card. Do you know if the Cuban government has different rules for Haitians?

Comment: Do you need to go through Cuban immigration to get my next flight through Mexico City? Can I sleep at La Habana international airport?